# Why angular binding don't work with service primitives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have an example [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iwVBoeyfBJPV87JQM4uS?p=preview). Why binding onto `count: 0` not working ? Here is code from *.js file:

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("objectCtrl", function($scope, sharingData) {   $scope.message = sharingData.message; });

app.controller("primitiveCtrl", function($scope, sharingData) {   $scope.count = sharingData.message.count; });

app.controller("watchCtrl", function($scope, sharingData) {   $scope.message = {};

  $scope.$watch(function() {
    return sharingData.message.count;   }, function(value) {
    $scope.message.count = value;   }); });

app.factory('sharingData', function() {   return {
    count: 0,
    message: {
      count: 0
    }   }; });

app.run(function($rootScope, sharingData) {   $rootScope.Inc = function() {
    sharingData.message.count = ++sharingData.count;   }; });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the variable is not passed by reference but by value.

In order to achieve that, you are forced to do this:

```
app.controller("primitiveCtrl", function($scope, sharingData) {   
    $scope.count = sharingData.message;
});
```

And:

```
  count from primitiveCtrl:   {{count.count}}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/h8A8PwGJuhD2imRbEsNM?p=preview

**EDIT**: the fact is that it's not possible to pass by reference a primitive value in javascript. One thing that might resemble this is the following:

```
app.controller("primitiveCtrl", function($scope, sharingData) {   
    $scope.getValue= function(){
      return sharingData.message.count;

    };
});
```

And:

```
  count from primitiveCtrl:   {{getValue()}}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/h8A8PwGJuhD2imRbEsNM?p=preview

Comment: In this case you are still using sharingData.message not sharingData.message.count the OP want the difference b/w two :-P

Comment: you got +1 for  function demo here :-)